# get-ADUser with parameters in a foreach loop from csv with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I try to lookup AD with powershell 3 and check if users (sAMAccountName) in my csv are existing and active in AD. However I am hopping from one error to the next one probably based on brackets and parenthesis but I do not find the correct way. I tried different filters, tried to pass them through a variable but I end up with "a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name -eq...". It looks like the error is at Get-ADUser as $adsearch is not set therefore fails to evaluate if($adsearch).

the csv file is sanitized (leading spaces etc.) and looks like (only one column with SAMAccountName):

```
john.doe
jane.doe
doej2
foo.bar
barf5
```

```
param ($inputfile='.\users.csv',$logfile='.\log.csv')
$csv = Import-CSV $inputfile

#"samAccountName,Search Result" | Add-Content $logfile

ForEach ($user in $csv){
    echo $user;
    #$adsearch = Get-ADUser -Filter 'sAMAccountName -eq "$($user)" -and Enabled -eq $true'
    #$filter = "sAMAccountName -eq $($user) -and Enabled -eq $($true)"
    #Write-Host "Filter is $filter"
    $adsearch = Get-ADUser -Filter "(sAMAccountName -eq '$($user)') -and (Enabled -eq '$($true)')"
    echo $adsearch
    if ($adsearch){
        echo "Found";
        echo "$error"
        #"$user, Found" | Add-Content $logfile
        }
    else{
        echo "NOT FOUND";
        echo "$error"
        #"$user, Not Found" | Add-Content $logfile
        }
    }
```

---

Solved.

For reference I leave the buggy script above, here is the working script (thanks Tomer and Charlie Joynt):

```
param ($inputfile='.\users.csv',$logfile='.\log.csv')
$csv = Import-CSV $inputfile

"samAccountName,Search Result,Error" | Add-Content $logfile

ForEach ($user in $csv){
    $username = $user.SAMAccountName;
    $adsearch = Get-ADUser -Filter {(samAccountName -eq $username) -and (Enabled -eq $true)}
    echo "search for active user $user"
    if ($adsearch){
        echo "Found";
        "$user, Found" | Add-Content $logfile
        }
    else{
        echo "NOT FOUND";
        "$user, Not Found, $error" | Add-Content $logfile
        }
    }
```

Comment: Giving an example of the structure of your input data helps with these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 1):

For the CSV file you showed, when I add a header line `SAMAccountName`, the following works for me:

```
$username = $user.SAMAccountName
$adsearch = Get-AdUser -Filter {(samAccountName -eq $username) -and (Enabled -eq $true)}
```

Notice the curly brackets instead of the quote marks.

Comment: Agree about being careful with `$user` w.r.t the structure of the CSV file. Typically CSV files will have multiple columns, in which case `$user` will refer to a *row* from the CSV file rather than a specific value and you'd need to identify the relevant property by (column) name, e.g. `$user.samAccountName` if **samAccountName** is a column in the CSV.

Comment: Tomer, thanks for your suggestion, however now I get the error: Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized at filelocation:11 char:14
+ $adsearch = Get-ADUser -Filter {(samAccountName -eq $user) -and (Enabled -eq $t ...
Do I have to use Get-ADObject or -LDAPFilter instead of?

Comment: How does your `$user` object look like? Is it a string with the user SAM account name?

Comment: yes it is a string containing the SAM account without spaces but it may contain a dot between first and last name, eg. john.doe or doej9. When I place a valid username directly in that query in a powershell w/o the script it works. That's why I echo the variables so often to check if they are ok

Comment: Could you show an example of the CSV format you're using?

Comment: Added the csv content it in the question

Comment: Notice that PowerShell will parse the CSV file as if the first line is the header, and each line is an object with one property, defined by the first line. So if you want to use CSV, make sure that the first line is `SAMAccountName`, and use `$user.SAMAccountName` instead of `$user`.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the CSV specific information.